# Genetic algorithm. A population contains chromosomes, that don't perform conditions. What should I do with?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on Traveling Salesman Problem solution with a Genetic Algorithm.
Some chromosomes are contain the shortest way, but they still aren't appropriate.

For example, a salesman must get to the A city at 6.00 pm, but using the solution of a chromosome he'll get there at 7.00 pm. Thus, this  solution is not correct.

What should I do with this issue?

Firstly, I can change these chromosomes. But how can I do it?

Secondly, I can keep them. How should I do the selection then?

Thirdly, I can replace them, but I have no idea what should I use instead.

Could you please help me or recommend me some useful information?

English is not my native language, so sorry if I said something wrong.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "chromosome", but couldn't you impose a penalty of some sort?  It's hard to say without more details.

Comment: Question might be suitable for http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution in my opinion to make the samples carrying these chromosomes unvital.

This means, that at each iteration of your Genetic Algorithm, possible solution that carries that chromosome "dies". This will make sure that the population carrying this chromosome will remain extremely small, and will not be able to "reproduce" for next generations, and will not be an issue - because samples having this chromosome cannot become dominant in the population.

Answer (score 0):

Do not kill the chromosomes if it's not necessary.
Kill the chromosomes only if the population became too large.
Simply Use the crossover and mutation operators, maybe with an elitist sampling strategy.

PS:
Have you read the book of Zbigniew Michalewicz about Genetic Algorithms?
I'm pretty sure it contains an example with the Salesman Problem

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a problem with constraints. Using GAs to solve such problems can be tricky, but there are generally four possibilites of how to deal with constraints:

1. Use such representation that makes the solutions always valid.
2. Don't use any constraint-preserving representation but introduce some correction operator which makes a valid solution out of an invalid one.
3. Penalize (or kill) the invalid solutions.
4. Use a multi-objective algorithm (e.g. NSGA-II, my favourite one) and turn the constraints into objectives.

The last option is very effective but you need to be able to measure **how much** is a constraint violated. If this is possible, which seems to me that it is in your case - you can just sum the differences between the desired and actual time of the visit, then this measure of the constraint violation just becomes another objective and you optimize the original objective and the new one(s) at the same time. This approach enables the algorithm to exploit useful information in all individuals even if they are invalid.